# Basic user interface, run nodes,

Tags: ros, nodes, create, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible for me to create an User Interface which allow me to run some nodes by just clicking buttons without typing codes in the terminal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200307/basic-user-interface,-run-nodes,/) by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a package called [node_manager_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/node_manager_fkie) for managing nodes, topics and so on with a GUI. You can use launch files as well as the buttons [in the GUI to launch the nodes](http://fkie.github.io/multimaster_fkie/chapter_usage/ros_nodes_view_and_control.html) that are not running or crashed.

---

Originally posted by [emreay](https://answers.ros.org/users/12731/emreay/) with karma: 90 on 2015-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-01-14**:
thanks for the reply. It helps me in a certain way. However, I failed to run some of the nodes. The error "usr/bin/screen is missing' appears. How can I fix this error? Does this have something to do with the OS that I am using?